# Shared preference for toggle button with time delay

Tags: android

I'm implementing a toggle switch which should switch off after specific time delay. But when I close the app it losses the current state of toggle switch. So I want to use shared preference for this purpose. But, in the following code my **shared preference stores the current state of switch but it doesn't turn off the switch after specified time delay**.

I have tried implementing shared preference to store the state of toggle switch. But, after closing the app and opening it again, it remembers the current state but doesn't turn off after specified time delay.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.tb1);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.vishal.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toggleButton.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("toggleButton", true));

    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.vishal.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", true);
                editor.apply();

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }, 10000);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uncheck", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: because you are running handle at `setOnClickListener` which is called when you click the button... and at on create (`setChecked`) you are not clicking or touching button so your handle is not called and button do not turn off

Comment: I'm a newbie here. Can you please tell me what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: when your app open and you set `toggleButton` on ... then also you want to turn it off after 10000  or only when user turn on by clicking it ??

Comment: No I want to turn it off after 10000 msec. after user clicks it; And even if user leaves the app the switch should be in a corresponding position according to time.

Comment: **And even if user leaves the app the switch should be in a corresponding position according to time**  I don't understand this... when user reopen app, what do you want to do with button

Comment: when user reopens the app, if the elapsed time is more than 10000 msec. switch should be off otherwise on.

Comment: how you will evalute this **if the elapsed time is more than 10000 msec** , when app is closed or killed ??

Comment: That's what I want to know. If it is not possible is there any other possible suggestion?

Comment: that don't seen to be logical to save your millisecond in shared preference..here what you can do is... when you app start if it is on start timer for 10000 and off it...else if it is off save its state

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is your question resolved ???

Answer (score 0):

try this concept, cancel the thread once your done.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.tb1);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs =               getSharedPreferences("com.example.vishal.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE);

         toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
                if(toggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor =     getSharedPreferences("com.example.vishal.togglebutton",     MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                     editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", false);
                     editor.apply();
                 }
                  else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.vishal.togglebutton", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                      editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", true);
                      editor.apply();
                 }
           }
        });

         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                                      toggleButton.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("toggleButton", false));
                   }
                }, 10000);
          }

      }
```

Comment: This will ON the button if Off state is saved in sharedprefrence